# Embeding XAML resource in a C++/CLI assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, xaml, resources, c++-cli

I'm trying to embed a XAML file as a resource of my C++/CLI project (Using DevStudio 2005). I found few ways to do it but none of them is working properly.

Method 1. Embed it as a native resource
I used the .rc file to include the .xaml. I can easily load it using the native Win32 calls. Problem: the project is not recompiled if I change the xaml file.

Method 2. Embed it using the linker
I used the linker option "Embed Managed Resourcfe File" and added my xaml file there. I can easily use GetManifestResourceStream() after to load it. Problem: the project is not recompiled if I change the xaml file.

Method 3. Embed it using "Add Existing Item"
I tried to add the xaml file using "Project->Add->Existing Item" and then open my xaml file. Problem: When I popup the xaml file properties, I cannot find any "Build Tool" to compile/embed it. Can I get it from somewhere? Is there a command line I can use as a custom build step?

Method 4. Embed it using a .resx file
I tried several things but I never managed to load it at runtime using GetResourceStream(). For this one I would need a step-by-step procedure.

Can someone please tell me which method I should be using?